# Access ASP.NET 5,MVC 6 Account Controller with CORS

Tags: cors, asp.net5

The _userManager.CreateASync(model) throws CORS issue when you try to register a new user, using CORS, even after you have enabled CORS properly.Is there a way to register  a new user using CORS in ASP.NET Core/MVC 6

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in web config within system.webserver tag

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I tried that and the error I get is XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:53210/account/register. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This is because I'm also using app.UseCors("AllowAll") in my startup.cs because for token authentication , I need that along with code such as  context.Response.Headers.Add(corsHeader, new[] { "*" }); in my OpenIdConnectServer derived class  to get a token. Now when I take that code app.UseCors("AllowAll") out from my starup.cs and try again, I get an error:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:53210/account/register. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Answer (score 0):

Call another cors enabled web api post method and then invoke the actual register method. That works.